# How to generate a 64 bit parse?

Tags: bison

```
how can I compile parse.y file to generate a 64 bit parse.tab.c file. 

I want to create a 64 bit c++ type parser with bison and lex 


-I have a parse.y file
-I compile it to genrate a parse.tab.cpp file
-I renamed it to parse.cpp and included it in my project
-I migrated this project to 64 bit
```

Do I need to compile this parse.y file separatly using a 64 bit bison exe and then include it in my 64 bit migrated project or the application will work file whithout compiling this parse.y file separatly using a 64 bit bison exe

Comment: I need to generate a 64 bit parse for verifying migration of my project. Can anyone tell how can I generate a 64 bit parse?

Answer (score 1):

with gcc you can use -m32 or -m64 option to compile alternatly in x86 or x64 bit code

Comment: Do I need to compile this parse.y file separatly? won't the tab.c file generated with 32 bit bison work for 64 bit platform if I migrate the project including this tab.c file ?

Comment: this brief tutorial may help you http://www.progtools.org/compilers/tutorials/cxx_and_bison/cxx_and_bison.html

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think there would be 32/64 issues in the generated code?  Just compile the output, it works.

Comment: :So you mean , I'll have exactly same "tab.c" file generated as output on compiling the ".y" file either 32/64 bit bison exe

Comment: FYI, at last as Bison 2.3, the result causes a warning when it tries to shove an int into a short with "*yyssp = yystate;"